# Pointers, casting and different compilers

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, casting

I am now taking an ANSI C programming language course and trying to run this code from lecturer's slide:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    double *p;

    for (p = (double*)a; p<(double*)(a+5); ((int*)p)++)
    {
        printf("%d",*((int*)p));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. On MacOS, XCode, Clang I get an error:`"Assignment to cast is illegal, lvalue casts are not supported"` and on Ubuntu gcc I get the next error: `"lvalue required as increment operand"`

I suspect that issue is compiler as we learn ANCI C and it has its own requirements which can violent other standards.

Comment: I think the compiler is right and the slide is wrong, the `((int*)p)++` part looks shady at best.

Comment: A cast is an operation. The result of a cast isn't a value that you can *assign to*. So the slide *is wrong*. That is pretty much it.

Comment: This is horrible code and it doesn't really illustrate anything useful other than how not to write valid, readable code. I have serious doubts about the competence of your lecturer.

Comment: @Anatoly: Care to post it in such a way that it can at least be *tried* to be compiled.

Comment: What was this slide supposed to demonstrate?

Comment: In C99 and as far as I know before a cast does not yield an lvalue and therefore the operation is invalid.

Comment: @WedaPashi o.k. I see that it has been edited by 2rs2ts, I'll take into an account this in future.

Comment: It's `ANSI` and no, it doesn't **violate** other standards. It's also known as `ISO C`.

Comment: @Barmar scanning array by using pointers of different types

Comment: Is the lecturer giving a course on obfuscated C programming? What's the point of doing all this? There could be a better example for demonstrating typecasting and dereferencing.

Comment: The correct way to write it would be `p = (double*)((int*)p + 1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Regarding `((int*)p)++`:

The result of `(int *) p` is a value. This is different from an lvalue. An lvalue (potentially) designates an object. For example, after `int x = 3;`, the name `x` designates the object that we defined. We can use it in an expression generally, such as `y = 2*x`, and then the `x` is used for its value. But we can also use it in an assignment, such as `x = 5`, and then the `x` is used for the object.

The expression `(int *) p` takes `p` and converts it to a pointer to `int`. The result is only a value. It is not an lvalue, so it does not represent an object that can be modified.

The `++` operator modifies an object. So it can only be applied to an lvalue. Since `(int *) p` is not an lvalue, `++` cannot be applied to it.

The code from the slide, as you have shown it, is incorrect, and I would not expect it to work in any C implementation. (C does permit implementations to make many extensions, but extending C to permit this operation would be unusual.)

### Regarding `(double*)a` and `(int*)p`:

C does permit you to convert pointers to objects to pointers to different kinds of objects. There are various rules about this. An important one is that the resulting pointer must have the correct alignment for the type it points to.

Objects have various alignment requirements, meaning they must be placed at particular addresses in memory. Commonly, `char` objects may have any address, `int` objects must be at multiples of four bytes, and `double` objects must be at multiples of eight bytes. These requirements vary from C implementation to C implementation. I will use these values for illustration.

When you convert a proper `double *` to an `int *`, we know that the resulting pointer is a multiple of four, because it started as a multiple of eight (assuming the requirements stated above). So that is a safe conversion. When you convert an `int *`, to a `double *`, it may have the wrong alignment. In particular, given an array `a` of `int`, we know that either `a[0]` or `a[1]` must be improperly aligned for a `double`, because, if one of them is at a multiple of eight bytes, the other one must be off by four bytes from a multiple of eight. Therefore, the conversions from `int *` to `double *` in this code are not defined by the C standard.

They might work in many C implementations, but you should not rely on them.

The C rules also state that when a pointer to an object is converted back to its original type, the result is equal to the original pointer. So, the round-trip conversions in the sample code would be okay if the alignment rules had been obeyed: You can convert an `int *` to a `double *` and back to an `int *`, provided alignment requirements are obeyed.

If the `double *` had been used to access a `double`, that would violate aliasing rules. Generally, C does not define the behavior when an object of one type is accessed as if it were another type. There are some exceptions, notably with character types. However, simply converting pointers back and forth without using them to access objects is okay, except for the alignment problem.